# Differences between /init and /sbin/init

Tags: linux, boot, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, init

In Linux boot order, the kernel will execute `/sbin/init`, however, I can see another file `/init` existing in the file system on my linux (CentOS 8 WSL2, Ubuntu 20 WSL2).

They are different binaries:

```
$ diff /init /sbin/init
Binary files /init and /sbin/init differ
```

What are the differences between `/sbin/init` and `/init`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`/usr/sbin/init` or `/sbin/init` is the executable starting the **SysV** initialization system. For compatibility reason, when **`systemd`** is installed, it's an alias to an executable of the `systemd` world.

The executable `/init` is unusual, in a Linux system. I suggest to investigate the reasons why it's present. It could be the part of a malware.

Comment: You're right that it's unusual to find /init on the rootfs, however, it would be completely normal to find one inside an initramfs...

Comment: @Claude /init, it's in the official Ubuntu WSL2, downloaded as default from Windows Store. Shouldn't be an issue. However, i guess /init is used by kernel instead of /sbin/init-->/lib/systemd/systemd, and I can't use systemctl

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned WSL 2. Microsoft still runs special Linux kernel inside VM and because the goal is not to strictly emulate they introduced own custom `init` process: like what's the point to start cron/cups/X/etc in every distro you installed.

Microsoft altered `init` process to avoid useless resource consumption (according to expected use cases of WSL 2).

When you import a Linux distro image Microsoft adds own file `/init` which is shared among all distros!

Even more: according to [How does WSL/WSL2/WSLg work without systemd?](https://superuser.com/questions/1719393/how-does-wsl-wsl2-wslg-work-without-systemd) WSL 2 is utilizing a single VM to run all distros. So the kernel is the same and the instance of the kernel in memory is shared, separation is done though Linux namespaces.